# How to make table column divisions centered between content?

Tags: html, css

How can I make the cell borders centered between the contents of the cells on either side?

I have a navigation bar I made with a table:

[image]

But I want the dividers to be centered like this:

[image]

How can I do this (without using javascript)?

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bh9ah/1/)

### Html:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <a href="something"><div>
                something
                </div></a>
        </td>
        <td>
            <a href="something_else"><div>
                Asdf
                </div></a>
        </td>
        <td>
            <a href="long_somthing"><div>
                Extra Long Something
                </div></a>
        </td>
        <td>
            <a href="qwerty"><div>
                qwerty
                </div></a>
        </td>
        <td>
            <a href="stuff"><div>
                Things
                </div></a>
        </td>        
    </tr>
</table>
```

### CSS:

```
    table {
    width:100%;
    height:20px;
    border-spacing:0px 0px;
    background-color:#f6f6f6;
}

a {
  color:#696969;
  font-family:sans-serif;
  text-decoration:none;
  font-size:13pt;
    outline:none;
}

div:hover {
    color:#343434;
}
div:active, div:focus {
    outline:none;
    background-color:orange;
}

td {
  border-left:2px groove rgba(147,147,147,0);
  border-right:2px groove rgba(147,147,147,0);
  text-align:center;
  cursor:pointer;   
}

td:hover {
  border-left:2px groove rgba(147,147,147,.5);
  border-right:2px groove rgba(147,147,147,.5);
  color:#343434;
  background-color:rgba(255,255,255,.5);
}
td:first-child {border-left:none;}
td:last-child {border-right:none;}

div {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    padding:5px 0px;
}
```

Comment: Does the navigation need to be made with a `<table>`? It would be a lot easier to create this with `<ul><li><a href="#">Link</a></li></ul>` :)

Comment: Another option: http://jsfiddle.net/srRm5/

Comment: @misterManSam No it doesn't, but I couldn't get any better results with a list.. It must be justified so that can stretch to the width of the parent element.

Comment: @swider I would like the borders to be in the same place if possible (I thought I could do that with `border-collapse:collapse;` in a table, but it removed all the left borders..) and justified. Is there any way to do that without using javascript?

Comment: Sure, you could add `margin: 0 -3px;` to the anchors

Comment: @swider Brilliant! I tried setting `text-align:justify;` on the container div, but it didn't seem to work..

Comment: I like swider's styling of the anchor tag much better, but it can also be done with divs - http://jsfiddle.net/timspqr/bh9ah/4/